# How i can add permission to acl?

Tags: winapi, permissions, acl

How i can add rights to already existing ACL ,i use this code [code link](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/add-security-to-a-file.html)  ,but this code erases all old rights, how can I add rights to already existing rights?

Comment: Please add the code here instead.
Here are some guidelines to help you revise your question:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
and here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SetEntriesInAcl` to Create a new ACL that merges the new ACE into the existing DACL.
You may refer to the [Modifying the ACLs of an Object in C++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/modifying-the-acls-of-an-object-in-c--).